# Redirect Https to Http (Cpanel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect my https traffic to http, as I wait for my SSL renewal. Google Chrome keeps showing the certificate date invalid date error . I have tried to update my .htaccess but it's not working. Am trying to bypass the error message on Google. Is there a way I can redirect it through cpanel?

Comment: Using let's encrypt, you can get an SSL certificate in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The browser has to perform the operations in this order:

1. Establish SSL connection
2. Make HTTP request over it
3. Get response

You can't get the response which says "Use HTTP instead" without getting through step 1, which is where the browser warns the user about the problem you are trying to hide.